# Can I use POST method to get data and GET method to post data?

Tags: http

Can I use `POST` method to get data from the server and `GET` method to post data to the server?

Comment: What platform you are working on, what language

Comment: A POST request can have a response, but a GET request can't have a body (well technically it can, but there's surprisingly few systems that support it). Therefore this question makes no sense. Please explain what you're trying to do, and read [ask] and share your research.

Answer (score 2):

[`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) and [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) methods exist for different purposes. Their semantic and use are described in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), one of the references for the HTTP/1.1 protocol.

See the quotes below:

> [**4.3.1.  GET**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)
>
> The `GET` method requests transfer of a current selected representation
> for the target resource.  `GET` is the primary mechanism of information
> retrieval and the focus of almost all performance optimizations.
> Hence, when people speak of retrieving some identifiable information
> via HTTP, they are generally referring to making a `GET` request.
>
> [...]
>
> A payload within a `GET` request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.
>
> The response to a `GET` request is cacheable; [...]

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics.  For example, `POST` is used for the following
> functions (among others):
>
> - Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
>   form, to a data-handling process;
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
>   blog, or similar group of articles;
> - Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the
>   origin server; and
> - Appending data to a resource's existing representation(s).
>
> [...]
>
> Responses to `POST` requests are only cacheable when they include
> explicit freshness information. However, `POST` caching is not widely implemented.