# Fetch hook based on router params doesn't work on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I fetch property data through params. In this property data are ID's of agents located. So, after successfully fetching the property data, I want to fetch the agents data through the just received ID's. The problem, if I manually refresh the page, the agent data isn't fetching. If I enter the page through the app navigation, it will.

Why is that? Or do I have to change something in the structure of how I fetch the data?

```js
async fetch() {
  try {
    const property = await this.$axios.$get(
      `/api/get-specific-property/${this.$route.params.id}`
    )

    if (property.success) {
      this.property = property.data

      const agentIDs = property.data.agents
      this.getAgents(agentIDs)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
},
```

```js
methods: {
  async getAgents(agentIDs) {
    try {
      const agents = await this.$axios.$post('/api/get-specific-agents', agentIDs)

      if(agents.success) {
        this.agents = agents.data
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The given code should be working fine even on a page reload. Do you have any error in your console or some strange state in your Vue devtools?

Comment: Nope, can't see anything unusual...

Comment: You could try `await this.getAgents(agentIDs)`, not sure if it helps in your case. Which code is not working, the method or the lifecycle? You're using SSG/SSR I guess. `fetch` behaves well with this setup usually.

Comment: That solves the problem...thanks! The method did not work and I'm using SSR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably await your method with the following

```js
await this.getAgents(agentIDs)
```

The rest looks fine!

Answer (score 1):

Using SSR `fetch()` is run by default on serverSide

- if You specify `fetchOnServer: false` then it's only happening on clientSide

@PhilippeUn it could be cleaner to use `async/await` syntax instead of `try/catch`. But for sure easier to resolve the both of APIs call in fetch hook. (Then always You can use `this.$fetch()` and it'll re-run the hook.)

- it allows to use the `$fetchState.error/pending` state
- Just a hint to stop using `console.log` for error, try to use `console.error` as it makes trace of the errors.

**But my main concern is that there's used $POST method to GET data? [Use GET for requesting data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39386535/10900851)**

I understand that by POST You can use BODY in the request but it makes a lot of risks for the backend.

Comment: By default, it runs on both server and client side. As for the POST, maybe OP is using some 3rd party API and you don't always have a choice for those.

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting me. ;) About the API, ofc it depends but looks that's their endpoint, it's the same one, so for sure it break the SRP rule. :<

Comment: Hello! I'm always interested in improving my workflow. Can you show me an example without try, catch or how you would do it? 

I think I'm not using a 3rd party API - what would be a 3rd party API for example? Where can I read through? 

How can I send my data to the backend without POST? What are the risks with my current approach?

Comment: That's nice. :) The case here is that GET method should be used to request data from backend. They way You're doing here is that You're sending `agentsIds` by POST with Body to the backend to request agentsData, where POST is supposed to modify smth. You should follow best API principles and start requesting data by GET, using queryParams as agentsIds Array which backend can read so example: `'/api/get-specific-agents?ids=1,2,3,4,5,6'`  . Backend should resolve it and send back the agentsData. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: The second topic is that API statusCode should be used as information about `success`  in any of the http requests. So then You don't have to check smth like `if (property.success) { ... }` because for ex. statusCode `404` will pass the info that the requested resource is not found.

Comment: I would like to recommend to read: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rest-api-best-practices-rest-endpoint-design-examples/ & https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/ :)

Comment: As You're using SSR I've thought You want to make it render on server, so here is  short example how I'll do it, but ofc -> don't have access the the API & etc so cannot fully check it ;) just an example (with `$fetchState` statuses): https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-wftpkp?file=pages/index.vue

Comment: Thanks for all that new stuff! I will give it a try and implement it. Looks great!